# White lines in ViewController on Screen Rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am new to iOS development. I encountered the problem, when I rotate the screen on iPhone X emulator I got white stripes on the side of the screen as you see on the second picture.[image]

[image]

I have already set background for ViewController and for TableView.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = Colors.backGround
    view.tintColor = Colors.backGround
```

It did not help. When the app starts from landscape mode the issue disappears.

Comment: Give iphone X constraint from safe area

Comment: @SaurabhJain I added TableView via anchor
        uiTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        uiTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        uiTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false Can you give futher reference

Comment: This is iPhoneX safe area. You must create view over this

Comment: Have you used `Autolayout` programmatically for constraints ?

Comment: Have you created `tableView` programmatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Your blue view area has `leading` and `trailing` constraint to `safe area`.
Just make it to `superview`.

[image: Trailing and leading constraint]

**EDIT:**
Here is code for same to achieve with swift code

```
//Creating tableview
let tableView = UITableView()
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tableView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
tableView.dataSource = self
self.view.addSubview(tableView)

//Setting layout of tableview
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

//Setting insets for respect safe area
tableView.contentInset = self.view.safeAreaInsets
```

Here are screenshots for same.

Vertical
[image: Add UITableView with programming coding vertical]

Horizontal
[image: Add UITableView with programming coding horizontal]

Comment: Thank you, how to do it without Storyboard

Comment: uiTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview?.widthAnchor ?? view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        uiTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview?.heightAnchor ?? view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true  This one  did not help

Comment: Thank you, the part with storyboard works fine. The anchors didn`t give any help. It works with simple Cell but not with my cell class.

Comment: You can also do same with your custom cell (I mean safe area replace by superview)

Answer (score 0):

If you created `UITableView` Programmatically 
then follow the below steps

```
private let tableView = UITableView()
```

then

```
func setupView() {
  tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

then

```
func setupConstraints() {

      self.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.tableView.superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor), constant: 0).isActive = true
      self.tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.tableView.superview.leadingAnchor), constant: 0).isActive = true
      self.tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.tableView.superview.trailingAnchor), constant: 0).isActive = true
      self.tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.tableView.superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor), constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your leading and trailing (or left and right) constraints for `tableView` from safe area to superview and the table will fill the screen horizontally.

Alternatively, just set the background color of the white view to that of the table view. That will ensure your table view content is always visible because it will stay inside the safe area (I'm assuming the white view is `self.view` here):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor
}
```